# Placing blocks client-side with filtering enabled in ROBLOX Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make my minigame place work with Filtering Enabled (anything done client-side like creating a part doesn't effect anything serverside). Only thing that is broken at the moment is one minigame.

The minigame's gameplay consists of the player placing down blocks to stop being sucked out into space due to decompression.

The placing of the blocks is done client-side so obviously it doesn't work properly with Filtering Enabled being on. I've tried fixing this via a remote-event that's called everytime the player tries to place a block with the arguments being the block being placed and the CFrame where it's being placed. However, everytime I test this via local server, it tells me that the argument 'part' is nil, even though I do give it.

Here's the relevant code from the relevant scripts:
Server script:

```
pBEvent.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player,partToPlace,position)
    partToPlace.Parent=sp.Blocks
    partToPlace.CFrame=position
    wait()
    partToPlace:MakeJoints()
    partToPlace.Anchored=false
end)
```

Local script:

```
m.Button1Down:connect(function()
    if m.Target and m.Target.Name == script.Parent.Parent.Name and amount.Value > 0 and db == false or m.Target.Name == "Part" and db == false and amount.Value > 0 then
        db = true 
        amount.Value = amount.Value - 1
        local lastpos = drag.CFrame
        local dragc = drag:Clone()
        dragc.Anchored = true

        dragc.Name = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name

        dragc.Transparency = 0
        dragc.ff:Destroy()
        event:FireServer(dragc,lastpos)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing dragc to the server which is a clone of drag, but drag is not present in the code. Try to clone m.Target:

```
m.Button1Down:connect(function()
    if m.Target and m.Target.Name == script.Parent.Parent.Name and amount.Value > 0 and db == false or m.Target.Name == "Part" and db == false and amount.Value > 0 then
        db = true 
        amount.Value = amount.Value - 1
        local lastpos = m.Target.CFrame
        local dragc = m.Target:Clone()
        dragc.Anchored = true

        dragc.Name = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name

        dragc.Transparency = 0
        dragc.ff:Destroy()
        event:FireServer(dragc,lastpos)
    end
 end)
```